# REST-based service - handling empty strings

Tags: wcf, rest

I have developed a REST-based web service. This service takes four parameters. The last two of these parameters may be empty strings. My question is, what is the recommended approach for dealing with empty strings?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean? If its not there do nothing. If its required and its not there send a 400.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options here - either define the parameters in the UriTemplate of the operation as *query variables* (and not *path* variables), or if this is not a GET operation, you can let the operation body receive them.

Case 1:

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate="/GetData?x={x}&y={y}&z={optional1}&w={optional2}")]
string GetData(int x, int y, string optional1, string optional2);
```

Case 2:

```
[WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
string DoSomething(int x, int y, string optional1, string optional2);
```